# While Loop not breaking (Python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've worked with while loops and the such before, but this one simply won't reach the conditions to break. This game is about finding hidden things in boxes. I've put a little bit of code that won't be there in the actual game that helps me verify what box is being hidden. The range of boxes is from 1 to 5 inclusive and is random each time the game starts again. I've started with the guess-box as false as I needed something to fill the space and turned the in_box into a string just in case.

```
from random import randrange
in_box = randrange(1, 5)
str(in_box)
guess_box = False
print("To guess which box enter in the numbers that each box relates to, eg, Box 1 will be the number 1! Ready? Set? Go!")
while guess_box != in_box:
    print(f"I was in box {in_box}")
    guess_box = input("Which box? ")
    if guess_box == in_box:
       print("Great job, you found me!")
       break
    else:
       print("I'm still hiding!!")
print("Thank you for playing")
```

Comment: `str(in_box)`. In place?

Comment: "but this one simply won't reach the conditions to break." In your own words, why *should* it ever? Can you give an example of something the user could `input`, that would match the `in_box` value? Hint: what is the *type* of `in_box`? What is the type of the `input` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cast the input to an integer type, the default type for input() is str.

the result is logic like '1' == 1 , which is false so the condition never passes.

```py
from random import randrange
in_box = randrange(1, 5)
str(in_box)
guess_box = False
print("To guess which box enter in the numbers that each box relates to, eg, Box 1 will be the number 1! Ready? Set? Go!")
while guess_box != in_box:
  print(f"I was in box {in_box}")
  guess_box = input("Which box? ")
  if int(guess_box) == in_box:
     print("Great job, you found me!")
     break
  else:
     print("I'm still hiding!!")
print("Thank you for playing")
```

works, note int() around guess-box in if condition.

Comment: Feels like `in_box = str(randrange(1, 5))` is closer to what OP was trying to do, as indicated by the `str(in_box)` expression. Also calling `str` on the value won't throw an error, while `int(guess_box)` will if the user enters non-numeric characters.

Comment: Actually, the `str(in_box)` would be unecessary on this example (you're not saving the generated string).

Comment: All true, tbh, I didn't read most of the code I just knew it would be a type mismatch so fixed that to make the example work.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting in_box to a string and not saving it. you need to do `in_box=str(in_box)`:

```
from random import randrange
in_box = randrange(1, 5)
in_box = str(in_box)
guess_box = False
print("To guess which box enter in the numbers that each box relates to, eg, Box 1 will be the number 1! Ready? Set? Go!")
while guess_box != in_box:
  print(f"I was in box {in_box}")
  guess_box = input("Which box? ")
  if guess_box == in_box:
     print("Great job, you found me!")
     break
  else:
     print("I'm still hiding!!")
print("Thank you for playing")
```

Without this, the condition to break the loop is never met.